# How to reset Apache

Tags: php, apache, fedora

I installed apache server using `sudo dnf install httpd`. I started and enabled the httpd service. I installed php using `sudo dnf install php`. The Apache welcome page appears.

Then I wrote this program and moved it into /var/www/html:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

The program is called index.php which should load when I go to localhost. But I see this message instead:

[image: access denied output]

Where am I going wrong? I confirmed httpd is running(active).

**Edit:** I had messed up one of the httpd configurations last time. That's why I had to reinstall. I deleted the `/etc/httpd` directory and then re-installed but I feel the settings  have somehow persisted.

**Edit** `ls -al /var/www/html` gives this output:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root  4096 Jan 23 18:10 .
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root   root  4096 Jan 23 18:10 ..
-rwxrwx---. 1 apache Hemil   20 Feb 17 18:17 index.php
```

Comment: What is the file owner/group of that file? What are the permissions? How is PHP installed? `ls -la /var/www/html` What does this output?

Comment: added it as edit @Quasimodo'sclone

Comment: Assuming apache version is 2.4+, you could add LogLevel trace5 in your apache config and check the apache log files and see why it's denying your access.

Comment: See in your apache environment variable configuration what the apache user is. On Debian it is `www-data`. As a bad workaround you could set read permissions to the world by `chmod o+r index.php`. On system not configured as shared hosting, file permissions could be `rwxr-x---`, owner set to the webmaster, group to the apache group `www-data` or whatever it is on fedora.

Comment: Usually the `apache` user is used to start apache's main process and write log files. There should be another more restricted user for handling requests coming from the net. However, I do not know how fedora is configured by default.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/355220/group-permissions-for-apache - looks as fedora might have another concept.

Comment: I typed in `httpd --verision` and it says `AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(13)Permission denied: AH00058: Error retrieving pid file /run/httpd/httpd.pid
AH00059: Remove it before continuing if it is corrupted.` I deleted that file to no use. I have messed up some configuration. How do I reset apache?

Comment: The FQDN message is not big issue, apache works even with this error message. This is when there is no `ServerName` was set in `httpd.conf` and the IP cannat be reverse resolved.

Comment: There might also be a SELinux conflict. This question should be answered by someone who is familiar with fedora.

Comment: Exactly. I want a fresh install of apache like it was never installed @Quasimodo'sclone

Comment: uninstall, install. On debian's `apt` package management only `purge` removes the configuration files as well. If there isn't something similar, ensure you remove the config-files by hand. Next time make a backup of the original config. Consider configuring virtual hosts and change only basic things in the main config.

Comment: This is a system administration question, and should be on unix.se or superuser.  When you post there, include your apache config and any virtualhost definitions

Answer (score 0):

Deleted the fedora paritition. Re-installed Fedora, apache and php. It works now